# IIS redirects admin to login page

Tags: asp.net, iis

This is in the web config file in my admin folder

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
   <authorization>
     <allow roles="Admin"/>
     <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

It worked while on development but after deploying it on the IIS server it redirects me to the login even after i log in as an Admin and try to go to the Admin folder pages.

How to fix it?

**NOTE : This worked perfectly before deploying to IIS.**

Comment: are all the settings on your web server the same as your dev environment? .net version especially.

Comment: .net version are the same .... what other server options do you recommend to check? ... as far as i know things are same

Comment: If i remove deny All User option of the foder in the IIS Manager then i can access the "Admin" foder.... but i want not to give access of this folder to non-admins ... what should i do???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem! Always use `applicationName` in your providers.

For more info on IIS troubleshooting go [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/security-issues/troubleshooting-forms-authentication)