# IIS caching redirects seemingly without reason

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms, iis-10

I am working on an ASP.NET webforms application that is being deployed to one of our internal IIS servers.

When I run the website on my machine using IISExpress it runs fine, can access the admin directory, however whenever I deploy to the server I can no longer access the admin directory and it just redirects me to the login page.

I have no code anywhere that should redirect me to the login page, even going so far as to delete the directory and it still redirecting, which would lead me to believe its a browser caching issue. After clearing the browser cache same thing happens, redirects you to the login page.

Another weird thing is that it only does it based on your website login account, when I log in using my actual account it allows me in, but whenever I use a test account with different roles it then redirects me.

I have checked all the usual culprits, HTTP Redirect, Output caching, temp ASP.NET files, master config and the sites own `web.config` to no avail. I have tried restarting the website and the application pool to no avail, and I can't restart the actual server/iis instance since there are other websites running that cannot be shutoff.

EDIT - Upon renaming the admin folder to admin2 it is now working without issue, so its definitely something to do with IIS. There be ghosts.

Comment: You don't need to check anything else but FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules if redirection responses come from IIS.

Comment: This thread is similar to your question, you can refer to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828486/iis-redirects-admin-to-login-page
For more infomation on IIS troubleshooting, you can read this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/security-issues/troubleshooting-forms-authentication

Comment: @YurongDai its not similar. My website isn't using any authorization rules.